# Linking SDL2 and Clion

Tags: gcc, linker, sdl-2, mingw32, clion

I have clion pointing to SDL2 directories and libs, but it fails to link the libraries when I try to build. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**CMakeLists:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(cavestory_development)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -lSDL2")

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR C:/SDL2-2.0.3/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2)

set(SDL2_LIBRARY C:/SDL2-2.0.3/i686-w64-mingw32/lib)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(cavestory_development ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(cavestory_development ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

**Build errors:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\conne_000\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\8a943732\8a943732\Debug --target cavestory_development -- -j 8
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cavestory_development.exe
CMakeFiles\cavestory_development.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:/Users/conne_000/Documents/ClionProjects/cavestory_development/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [cavestory_development.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\cavestory_development.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'cavestory_development.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cavestory_development.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cavestory_development.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cavestory_development.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cavestory_development.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cavestory_development] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cavestory_development' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example to get you started with SDL2 on windows
(`main.cpp` just contains the hello SDL from [LazyFoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php))

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(hello_sdl2)

# configure the SDL (cf. "SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\pkgconfig\sdl2.pc")
# C++ flags
set(SDL2_Flags "-mwindows -Wl,--no-undefined -static-libgcc")
# library paths
set(SDL2_ROOT     "D:/PATH/TO/SDL2-2.0.3/i686-w64-mingw32")
set(SDL2_Includes "${SDL2_ROOT}/include")
set(SDL2_LibDir   "${SDL2_ROOT}/lib")
# imported targets for CMake (cf. https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)
add_library(SDL2     STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(SDL2main STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET SDL2     PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2.a")
set_property(TARGET SDL2main PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2main.a")
# the libs to link against
# note: as always with gcc, the order is important...
set(SDL2_Libs mingw32 SDL2 SDL2main m dinput8 dxguid dxerr8 user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 shell32 version uuid)

# configure the project
# include the SDL flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ${SDL2_Flags}")
# collect the sources
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
# define the target
add_executable(hello_sdl2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
# include the SDL headers
target_include_directories(hello_sdl2 SYSTEM PRIVATE ${SDL2_Includes})
# link against the SDL (and its dependencies)
target_link_libraries(hello_sdl2 ${SDL2_Libs})
```

tested on Win8.1 64bits with [SDL2-2.0.3](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz), [MinGW-W64 i686-5.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and [CLion 1.2 EAP (build 142.5239.6)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Early+Access+Program)

Comment: I'm having problems with linking the libraries. My lib folders are located at ${SDL2_ROOT}/lib/x64 or ${SDL2_ROOT}/lib/x86. And also, the files libSDL2.a and libSDL2main.a does not exist. I used your link to download the lib.

Comment: If you've actually downloaded [SDL2-2.0.3](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz), you'll find everything you need under `${SDL2_ROOT}/i686-w64-mingw32`. cf. line #8

Comment: the flag "-mwindows" makes my "std::cout"s not work.

Comment: `-mwindows` is just used for hiding the console window (here are some old, but still relevant, [link1](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Setup) and [link2](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html) on the the use of `-mwindows`). `std::cout` works fine. You should be able to find the output in a `.txt` file in your executable's workind directory.

Comment: is it possible to avoid absolute path  "D:/PATH/TO/SDL2-2.0.3/i686-w64-mingw32" by, for example, find_library() or smth? 
Absolute paths are absolutely inapropriate.